# History of "dummy" as adverb?

Tags: etymology, slang, internet, intensifying-adverbs

The meme-y term "dummy thicc" uses "dummy" as an intensifier modifying "thicc" (meaning curvy). How common is this usage of "dummy"? How long has it been around? Is the etymology here related to the use of "stupid" or "crazy" as ironic intensifiers?

(Wiktionary lists ["Extremely"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dummy) as an adverb definition of "dummy", but without quotes or other background.)

Comment: I don't think it's too old, I've never heard of it before this question. But I'm also not into social media and memes.

Comment: I've also never seen "thicc" before.

Comment: Online OED doesn't include this sense of the word as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's on page 2 of [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dummy&page=2), the entry was added in 2019.

Comment: Because this is apparently slang and clearly not a common use of this word, I recommend including at least one decent example to show that it is actually in use.